# How to install TexLive 2012 in an unofficial distro based on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

I'm want to install an unofficial distro based on ubuntu 12.04, for old PC's

Comment: The same way as you would install texlive 2012 on an official distro?

Comment: may be this would help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67748/native-vs-distribution-specific-installation-method

Comment: What distribution are you talking about, exactly?

Comment: Bodhi Linux 2.1.0 and Precise Puppy Linux

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

- I installed the basic TeXLive packages from `synaptics` (as required by, e.g., `auctex`).
- Next I downloaded the big `iso` image from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html), mounted it, and installed it as usual (`sudo ./install-tl`, etc.).
- In `Options` I chose to create symbolic links, which replaced the older version's synlinks.
- Finally, I downloaded a fresh version of `tlmgr` from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html), installed it, and updated my system.

Now I have a fully functional, updated copy of TexLive 2012.

Comment: The manual download of `tlmgr` in the final step should not be necessary, since `tlmgr`can update itself.

Comment: Indeed. But sometimes it has happened to me (at least in previous versions) that `tlmgr` cannot be run unless first updated "the hard way".